# Cucumber + Capybara + Selenium test failing while trying to select a hidden radiobutton

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, automated-tests

I'm trying to check a radiobutton for a form submitting in RoR, which works in development and production but not when I run an automated test with Cucumber using the @javascript tag. The view is this:

```
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :contact_id, :value => @contact.id %>
  <ul id="categories" class="unstyled">
<% @new_categories.each do |priority| %>
<li class="span2 contact" id="category_<%=priority.category.id%>" style="margin:0 20px 20px 0;position:relative; background:white">
  <div class="contact-image">
    <%= image_tag(priority.category.image, :alt => priority.category.name) %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:category_id, priority.category.id, class: 'hidden') %>
  </div>

</li>

<% end %>
 </ul>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'submit', :id=>"submit_category", :class=>'hide' %></p>
 <% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('li').click(function() {
    var radio = $(this).find("input[type=radio]");
    radio.attr('checked', true);
    $('#submit_category').click();
});
</script>
```

If I put the script like this inside of the loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('li').click(function() {
        $("#model_category_id_<%=priority.category.id%>").attr('checked', true);
        $('#submit_category').click();
    });
</script>
```

It does work, but I find it inefficient. In the former solution, var radio returns an object (found this with alert()), but any calls I make on it (.name, .val(), .innerHTML) returns undefined.

Also, this is the step that clicks on the li element:

```
When /^I click on the "(.*?)" category$/ do |category_name|
  @category = Category.find_by_name(category_name)
  page.find('li', id: "category_#{@category.id}").click
end
```

The request is indeed made, but as if the radiobutton wasn't selected at all, and the steps after this one fail. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems the problem stems with the use of $(this). I also tried using $(event.target), but it has the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to click on radio button, which is hidden, add following in your env.rb

  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true

IMHO: Capybara ignore hidden element by default

- try to click on radio button (e.g., user xpath or something) and click on it not on li

Answer (score 0):

This question is from a year ago but maybe this will help someone...

The previous answer is half way there.  You do want to set: `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true`

then...

```
page.execute_script("$('element').show()")
choose('element')
```